# What is unicode character $(0) in DB2?

Tags: db2

While querying a DB2 database, I have a unicode char(3) field displaying a value of '$(0)$(0)$(0)'.  What does this represent?

Comment: With which tool are you submitting the SQL?  If you select HEX(column-name) what is the value?

Comment: I am using AQT.  HEX(column-name) shows the values as 000000. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary zero in utf-8 is U+0000      00000000 and is in the  control range.
Your display tool (aqt) chooses to display it as '$(0)$(0)$(0)'. 
A different tool may behave differently when displaying this column.
In the table, a program inserted/updated that column to binary zeroes.